# I am better than you or I am better than you are

Tags: sentence-structure

Which one of these two is correct? Is it necessary to write 'you are' instead of only 'you'?

Comment: It's just an unwanted distraction that you happen to have chosen a pronoun where the nominative and accusative forms are the same. It would probably be more useful to consider *"I am better than **him**"* vs *"I am better than **he** [is]"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct, replace the verb 'am' (which is current tense version of the verb 'be' as in 'to be') and you can see the structure better.

- I *am* better than you.
- I **dance** better than you.
- I *am* better than you *are*.
- I **dance** better than you **dance**.

Comment: I dance better than you do. - This should be the correct expression, i should think.

Comment: Indeed, although my point was to substitute the verb to demonstrate how it occurs twice in a sentence. I dance better than you do, or I dance better than you dance, would both be correct and perfectly acceptable: they still add a similar amount of emphasis

Comment: well in that case - i take it back

Comment: @Leo *I dance better than you* is perfect, idiomatic, everyday English. *I cook better than you*, *My wife speaks French better than me (or I)*. *The dogs guard the house better than the cats.*

Comment: @Leo *Than* can be a preposition "You dance better **than me**" or a conjunction "You dance better **than I do**".  (We need to replace *you*, as FumbleFingers points out, with a word with separate nominative and accusative forms for this question to be useful. I chose **I/me**.)

Answer (score 2):

If you write 'you are' then you are emphasizing it and nothing else.

So grammatically both are correct.

More examples

1. Virat is a better batsman than Suresh.
2. Virat is a way better batsman than Suresh is.
3. I got more brains than you.
4. I got more brains than you do.

Comment: I would say that 'I got' for 'I have', I have got' or 'I've got' is still generally regarded as non-standard, particularly in writing.

Comment: I'd agree with tunny, 'got' is not a verb in this context, you did not 'get' more brains (as in to retrieve), you 'have' or 'have got' more brains

Comment: well it was more hollywoodish style english (If you watch English movies regularyly, that's the English sentence style that comes to mind) As Americans they are allowed to speak a bit ungrammatical English, right ?

Comment: @Leo there is no such thing as "hoolywood style English." Movies reflect a wide variety of English usage. What is important is that *got* as a synonym for have* (as in *possess*) is not ungrammatical in everyday speech.

Comment: well - i can only agree with you (on the point where you say - there is no such thing as "hoolywood style English) if you are an American otherwise i tend to disagree. And by hollywoodish English i mean you find many sentences there which are ungrammatical from the British English perspective. That's it.

Comment: Hmm, some people *got* problems with your post, it seems. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

In a sentence with "I" vs. "you," I can see where adding or subtracting the "do" is a matter of style choice.

But in the sentence "Nobody knows your life better than you" there is room for ambiguity.

Without adding the "do," the meaning might also become "Nobody knows your life better than (they know) you."

Adding the "do," it becomes clearer that the meaning is "Nobody knows your life better than you (know your life) do."